# PowerEdge 2650 remote OS install

Tags: boot, installation, operating-system

I am needing to install an operating system on my Dell PowerEdge 2650 server, but i do not have a disk burner to make boot disks to install the operating system, so i am wanting to install the operating system remotely from another computer, i activated remote management and i connected the server to my mac mini using the remote management port on the server then i listened for open ports, port 445 was open, i then tried to make an ssh connection to the server but i had trouble authenticating.

What are the proper steps for remotely installing an operating system on the Dell PowerEdge 2650.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways you can go:

1. PXE boot and remote install (RIS on Windows, Anaconda/Kickstart on Linux)
2. Virtual CD/DVD via the remote access controller

Answer (score 1):

Should be fairly straightforward if you have decent bandwidth and Dell's DRAC remote management feature.

http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/systems-management/w/wiki/drac-5-virtualmedia-remote-windows-2008-server-install.aspx